# Quicker way of writing for each statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing VBA code to fill three different combo-boxes with the same data. I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing it then what I am doing at the moment?

```
' Create fac1 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
    With Me.cbo_fac1
    .AddItem c_fac.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next c_fac

' Create fac2 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
    With Me.cbo_fac2
    .AddItem c_fac.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next c_fac

' Create fac3 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
    With Me.cbo_fac3
    .AddItem c_fac.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next c_fac
```

Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One step further, possibly:

```
dim lLoop as long
' Create fac1 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
    For lLoop=1 to 3
        Me.controls("cbo_fac" & lLoop).AddItem c_fac.Value
        Me.controls("cbo_fac" & lLoop).List(Me.controls("cbo_fac" & lLoop).ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    next lLoop
Next c_fac
```

Comment: Nice answer, I couldnt remember me.controls ~ as the only time i've ever dynamicaly looped through objects like this someone had built them into a worksheet so I had to use '.OleObjects().Object.` instead of `.Controls().`

Comment: Unless you really have lots of objects, it rarely makes sense to call them through a loop like that, but it's served me a couple of times.

Comment: Nice, but why not just assign the range value to the combobox list? Additem is very slow

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you do this? :

```
' Create fac1 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
    With Me.cbo_fac1
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
    With Me.cbo_fac2
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
    With Me.cbo_fac3
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next c_fac
```

This reduces the number of time syou need to loop through the worksheet range by 2/3rds. Usually reading from and writing to the actual Excel worksheet objects are what takes the most time in Excel VBA code.

Comment: For better performance you could store `c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value` in a variable instead of retrieving it three times.

Comment: If you want to milk every possible bit of performance out of it, you can assign the whole range to an array, but you'll be hard pressed to see any difference in most scenarios.

Comment: True, but you don't need to add too many entries before you notice a performance hit using .additem, it's usually best not to use additem at all

Answer (score 2):

This would be much faster (on the assumption that "fac" is a column), .AddItem is very slow for > 5 entries:

```
Dim rng
rng = ws_misc.Range("fac").resize(,2).value
Me.cbo_fac1.List = rng
Me.cbo_fac2.List = rng
Me.cbo_fac3.List = rng
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I dislike `With` in this case. It doubles the number of lines of code with next to no benefit. You could shrink this all the way down to:

```
' Create fac1 cbo
For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")

    Me.cbo_fac1.AddItem c_fac.Value
    Me.cbo_fac1.List(Me.cbo_fac1.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Me.cbo_fac2.AddItem c_fac.Value
    Me.cbo_fac2.List(Me.cbo_fac2.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Me.cbo_fac3.AddItem c_fac.Value
    Me.cbo_fac3.List(Me.cbo_fac3.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value

Next c_fac
```